# yarn start:dev not working, not changes the code - Nest.js

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXv7p.png)

my code is returning the same value even if i change the code

I want to know what happened

Comment: try this: `rm -rf dist` and start again.
If it didn't work, you're doing something wrong lol

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to remove dist file first and build and rerun your project.

```
rm -rf dist
npm run build
npm run start:dev
```

I'm not sure you faced the issue while adding a new model or updated the schema of orm module.

If yes, According to this [link](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload#hot-reload) NestJS won't automatically copy your assets to the dist folder moreover as I described earlier is not compatible with glob static paths such as entities property in TypeOrmModule.

Comment: I am changing the return of the controller

Comment: I faced the same issue, whenever my NestJS does not update its behavior after I changed some code, removing the entire `dist` folder and rebuild the project usually solve the problem. But this is quite annoying if I do this every time. Much appreciate if anyone can explain what is behind the scene and how to correct it.

Comment: Yes man! I want to find out what's going on

Comment: @Kauan Could you share the entire package.json file of the project?
Basically, excepted handling new model of ORM, NestJS always applies new changes whenever you save a file.

Comment: @iyhc According to this [link](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload#hot-reload) webpack won't automatically copy your assets to the dist folder moreover as I described earlier is not compatible with glob static paths such as entities property in TypeOrmModule.

Comment: this is not the problem. Inside the dist folder, the file is compiled, but the return keeps the same

Comment: i tried to create another project but the error remains

Comment: I did what is written in this 'link' and I solved it, but I wanted to know why the application does not work with 'hot-reload'

Comment: @Kauan NestJS is basically provides hot-reload feature. Perhaps you are using lower version of node and nestjs. What version did you make a new NestJS project with? Have you followed up the exact steps on the [official website](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Add the rimraf lib:

`yarn add rimraf`

Then create a new script in the scripts section of the package.json:

`"prebuild":"rimraf dist"`

Comment: it's not working :(